# Replace custom object tab with a VF page/tab AND keep original SF classic looks

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension, list-view

Right now, I have a custom object `Errol__c`. It has its own custom tab.

I wish to make a `Visualforce Page` that will look *exactly* the same as when I press the custom object tab.

That is, there should be the icon, name of object, list view list and buttons and the table with all the records.

I know something like this can be done with a standard object/controller, however, what about custom objects/controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need *any* controller. The `<apex:enhancedList>` tag gives you a very similar view to the out of the box object tab. You can also set the `tabStyle` attribute.

```
<apex:page tabStyle="MyObject__c">
    <apex:enhancedList type="MyObject__c" height="300" rowsPerPage="10" />
</apex:page>
```

[image: Enhanced List]

Comment: Ok this is somewhat similar to what I require. Can it show the default list view (the one you get when you click a tab?)

Comment: I think it will show the most recent list view you have visited. Whatever the default behavior is, you certainly cannot control that aspect.

Comment: @fraglord Did that end up being what you were looking for?

Comment: Somewhat :) For now, I'll mark the question as answered, since it is the "correct" answer for the question, but I have decided to do something else.

Comment: for now, I just want to replace the default "New" button inner workings so that it displays a VF page instead of the default SF new record screen.

Comment: Sounds like a great new question! Make sure you do your research first!